# I get " {"status":false,"error":"false"} " in codignater .. why?

Tags: php, api

I  have an error in my code ,, I'm writing code in php framework `  codeignater ,, i want to extend REST_Controller but i can't , my code not working clearly,, please help me ,, here is my error and my code ,
{  "status": false, "error": false }

**controller / Auth.php**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

//require('libraries\REST_Controller.php');
require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

//require('libraries\Format.php');

class Auth  extends REST_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('api_model');
//        $this->load->library('rest_controller_lang');

    }

    function data_post()
    {
        $data = array(
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'surename' => $_POST['surename'],
            'email' => $_POST['email'],
            'password' => $_POST['password'],

        );
        $this->api_model->insert($data);
        $this->response("my first api");
        var_dump($data);
  }
}

?>
```

**models/Api_model.php**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Api_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function insert($data){
        if($this->db->insert('peoples', $data)){
            return FALSE;
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
}

?>
```

**config/autoload.php**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','REST_Controller');
```

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop the **application/libraries/Format.php** and **application/libraries/REST_Controller.php** files into your application's directories.Copy the **rest.php** into your ** application/config** directory.

For the code try referencing the controller directly.

```
<?php
  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

 require(APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

 class Auth extends \Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller
 {......}
```

I have added `namespace Restserver\Libraries;` in my REST_CONTROLLER

```
<?php
 namespace Restserver\Libraries;

  use Exception;
   use stdClass;

   defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

   abstract class REST_Controller extends \CI_Controller
    {......}
```

For the response try sending an HTTP Code along with it

```
$this->response("my first api", 200);
```

Comment: I have written everything you say, but now i have new error  :/ ,, Fatal error: Class 'Restserver\Libraries\CI_Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\application\libraries\REST_Controller.php ,,.. what can i do now ?

Comment: Not really sure but you can follow this tutorial that i used https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814 as well as the github project https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

Comment: i do searches everywhere ,, i ask everybody but my problem nobody can't resolve ,,, thanks,,,

Comment: @anushChakhoyan create an issue on the github page i'm sure they will be able to help you out